# IIS localhost page not found in windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7-x64

I have windows 7 64 bit ultimate OS. I need to install IIS on my laptop. From turn on/off windows features I enabled IIS by checking the checkbox in front of IIS management console. But it was not successful and then I re-enabled it by checking all the checkboxes under the web management tool. This time it was success and if I type inetmgr now I can find the window.
But the problem is when I type localhost on my browser address bar page does not come(404 page not found.)

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem was default web site not running because of port 80 uses by another application. Then I changed the port and re start the web site. Now it is working fine. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was default web site not running because of port 80 uses by another application. Then I changed the port and re start the web site. Now it is working fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Close all applications like Skype, DropBox, GoogleDisk, TeamViewer etc.
2. Type `iisreset` in Windows Console and press Enter
3. Start again all applications like Skype, DropBox, GoogleDisk, TeamViewer etc.

Whis way always working for me!

Answer (score 0):

In My System the Problem was not with port. When i installed Apache some iis service has got uninstalled. SO I removed IIS from the features and Add Again, then it works fine.